# JQuery regex remove spaces and replace comma in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to get keywords from the client and need to remove all spaces next to commas.

I have the following keywords list style

```
  ,air duster, apple,       samsung , power bank station,sony
```

I need like this

```
air duster,apple,samsung,power bank station,sony
```

my code

```
 $("#my-input").on("focusout", function() {  
    console.log("FOCUS OUT")

    $(this).attr("value",$(this).val().split(/[ ,]+/).join(',').trim());
  })
```

print

```
,air,duster,apple,samsung,power,bank,station,sony
```

Comment: `.split().map(x => x.trim()).join()`... thats it.

Comment: Use `.split(",").map(x => x.trim()).filter(Boolean).join(",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log(
    "  ,air duster, apple,       samsung , power bank station,sony".split(",").map(x => x.trim()).filter(Boolean).join(",")
)
// => air duster,apple,samsung,power bank station,sony
```

Here,

- `.split(",")` - splits with a comma
- `.map(x => x.trim())` - removes leading/trailing whitespaces
- `.filter(Boolean)` - removes empty items
- `.join(",")` - join the items with a single comma.

Answer (score -1):

```js
',air duster, apple,       samsung , '.replace(/, +/g, ',')
```

Comment: Might be better: `/\s+,\s+/`

Comment: sure - if there are other whitespace characters like tab